# Create a list from a string variable

Tags: python, string, list

I can create a complex list with manual input:

```
a = [{'1-3': [], '3-6': [47.4], '6-8': [], '8-12': [], '12-18': [], '18-25': [], '25-35': [], '35-55': [], '>55': []}]
```

but what if I have a string:

```
a_str = '{'1-3': [], '3-6': [47.4], '6-8': [], '8-12': [], '12-18': [], '18-25': [], '25-35': [], '35-55': [], '>55': []}'
```

Can I pass somehow this string as a parameter to create a list, like in manual input? Or the dictionary that sits inside, it doesn't matter

Comment: You could potentially do this with [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) or [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads).  However you might also consider re-thinking the problem - it's going to be really annoying for users if they have to type in a complicated expression each time they run the script.

Comment: originally I had a pandas DataFrame with list of dicts as values, I saved those into CSV. Now I am trying to rebuild my DataFrame.

Comment: @0x5453 It's not JSON. But `ast.literal_eval` should work fine.

Comment: @Barmar Well, it's also not a valid Python string because of the unescaped nested single quotes.  But with correct quoting it could be valid Python or JSON.

Comment: @0x5453 I take that as just poor copying. He's not really using literals, it's coming from a file

Comment: ast.literal_eval works good, thanx